# Layout with two fragments: one fragment and a fragment with the Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement the following design.
TextView should take up space by content, and the rest of the space is a map.

```
+----------------+
|                |
|    Map         | <-- id/fragment_container_1
|                |
|                |
+----------------+
|                |
|    TextView    | <-- id/fragment_container_2
|                |
+----------------+
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Client Label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

map.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_view_observer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
// map
Fragment fragmentMap = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ObserverMapFragment");
if (fragmentMap == null)   {
    fragmentMap = ObserverMapFragment.newInstance();
    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container_1, fragmentMap, "ObserverMapFragment");
}
// fargment 1
Fragment fragmentObserver = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ObserverFragment");
if (fragmentObserver == null)   {
    fragmentObserver = ObserverFragment.newInstance();
    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container_2, fragmentObserver, "ObserverFragment");
}
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

However, after that I get that the map occupies all visible space.

```
+----------------+
|                |
|                |
|    Map         |
|                |
|                |
+----------------+
```

Where I made a mistake? 
Maybe I'm wrong in the very architecture of the application with several fragments?

Comment: why dont you simply do that this way: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding ?

Comment: Well, I want to dynamically manage fragments.

Comment: you are managing with two fragment for it, whereas you can do it by using a single fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this

1. Add  **android:layout_height="0dp"**
2. Add **android:weightSum**

**Finally**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
              />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works 50% / 50%, I did this:

android:weightSum="4"

android:layout_weight="3"

android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: However, I would not want to touch main.xml

I would like to leave it universal. But, if this is not possible, then this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your main.xml like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: add android:layout_weight="1" in the fragment_container_1

Comment: It works, thanks, but I think that @"IntelliJ Amiya" answer is more complete.

Comment: ok.. but that answer is not actually the exact answer..it will always give you 50-50 layouts.. in your question youn mentioned that you need the size of textview to wrap the content

Answer (score -1):

Don't give a `textview` size and map size match parent.